# $_POST and $_FILES are sent empty but isset() doesn't recognize

Tags: php, isset

index.php passes firstName and an image to save.php via post.
Save.php is checking `$_POST` and `$_FILES` to be not empty via isset method.
when nothing is sent by POST it should give an error and dies but inside of if block never runs and if we print the array there is nothing in it. which means that nothing passed via `$_POST` or `$_FILES`.

when firstName and image are passed it works fine, but when nothing passed isset doesn't recognize it.why?

'error' field of `$_FILES` array has error code 4, which means 'No file was uploaded', in this case also if block should be execute but doesn't.

this is index.php

```html
<form action="save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
  pic: <input type="file" name="pic"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

and here is the save.php:

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['firstName']) || !isset($_FILES['pic'])) 
{
  die('input error');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

output:

```text
Array
(
    [firstName] => 
)
Array
(
    [pic] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [full_path] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: You might want to look into `empty()`, since `isset()` checks if the variable or array index exists, and it does.

Comment: Check for error 4 in the file, which you already know means the file is not uploaded.

Comment: @gre_gor the issue fixed here by the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form you making a post request and you actually sending an empty string or file in your case.
And `$_POST['firstName']` exist as an empty string;

Look at code blow:

```
$variable = "";

var_dump(isset($variable));
// This returns true because $variable is set and has a value (an empty string).

var_dump(empty($variable));
// This returns true because $variable is considered empty. An empty string is considered empty.

var_dump($variable == null);
// This returns true because when comparing an empty string to null using the == operator, they are considered equal.

var_dump(is_null($variable));
// This returns false because an empty string is not considered null.

var_dump($variable === null);
// This returns false because the === operator checks for both value and type equality. $variable is a string, while null is a null value, so they are not identical.
```

As you can see when you check with `empty($variable)` function it return true because it just check your `$variable` is `null` or not

You might wonder why `is_null($variable)` returns false, It is because `is_null($variable)` also checks if the $variable type is equal to `null` or not; in this case the `$variable` type is `string` but the value is `null`

So you can use do this:

```
<?php
if ( empty($_POST['firstName']) || $_FILES['pic']['error'] != 0) 
{
  die('input error');
}
```

`$_FILES['pic']['error']` will be equal to 0 if there is no errors

You can find other error codes of `$_FILES` on [php Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: yes, that works, empty() should be used instead of isset().

Comment: `$variable ="";

var_dump(isset($variable));
//This return false`  => this returns true because $variable just defined before